# I don't want to show Dependency-Track Project on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, owasp-dependency-track

I have integrated *dependency track* on **Jenkins **but I want to show only the vulnerability report (**Dependency-Track Report**) in Jenkins pipeline, I don't want to show the link to the project in the application (**Dependency-Track Project**)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxcyt.png)

I don't want to show, therefore, not even the writing "These results may not be up to date. Please visit the Dependency-Track project page for most recent results"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnUjg.png)

Is it possible to do it?

I don't want to show the Dependency-Track Project ref in Jenkins pipeline.

I tried changing the permissions in the **Teams** section, but if I try to remove "*View_Vulnerability/View_Portfolio*" the Dependency-Track Report is also removed (but I want this).